# Business activity monitoring in Activiti BPM

Tags: jbpm, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn

As you know that `Activiti BPM` does not have `BAM(Business activity monitoring)` as out-of-box feature. In their forum few says that it can be integrated with `BIRT` and `Pentaho` to achieve that. 
Here are few things i would like to know :

1. Has anybody implemented that, can you suggest how effective this approach of solving BAM problem?
2. Is there any other way or work around or tool to integrated with, to solve monitor business activity (BAM)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Activiti BPM, BIRT or Pentaho. But most business processes can be monitored simply with WSO2 BAM using an Activity ID as described in [Activity Monitoring Dashboard](https://docs.wso2.org/display/BAM240/Activity+Monitoring+Dashboard). What you have to do is to write custom data agent to intercept business processes.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is not with Activity, but from a technical perspective the integration should be quite similar to what we did.

In addition to the BAM features in its user portal we have integrated [Eclipse Stardust](http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/)  with Eclipse BIRT. (also see [architecture](http://www.eclipse.org/stardust/features/reporting.php) and [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.stardust.docs.reporting/html/reporting/toc.html) pages) We developed custom BIRT data source and data set extensions to allow users to design reports without SQL knowledge / knowledge of the database schema. This approach worked well for the mid/long term reporting requirements. A downside is that you need to adjust the plugins when you want to upgrade to a newer BIRT version.

For our operational / adhoc BAM requirements we did a POC that integrated the browser-based BIRT designer into the user portal. It worked, but did not really address our requirements. The feature set was too broad and the potential impact of an expensive report on a production system was a concern. We needed something more controlled with a more targeted feature set that is limited to the business user's requirements.

With the latest Stardust release we released a [preview of a new adhoc reporting portal perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.stardust.docs.enduser/html/handbooks/execution-clients/reports.html) that uses just plain HTML5. It limits the features to what is required for dashboarding in the context of a BPMS. This new reporting perspective will be released in the upcoming [Eclipse Luna release](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release) end of June.